# MSBuild and package restore with packages.config

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package

Is it possible to restore packages during the build using MSBuild only if projects are still using packages.config?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target

> MSBuild 16.5+ also has opt-in support for the packages.config format.

Use:

```
msbuild -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true -t:restore
msbuild -t:build
```

Comment: if anyone is trying to use this flag, it doesn't work.  
There is an official bug report: 
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11329

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: This answer was outdated by recent MSBuild enhancements. See @irvnriir [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209365/213871).

According to documentation[1]:

> The `restore` target works only for projects using the PackageReference
> format. It does **not** work for projects using the `packages.config`
> format; use nuget restore instead.

So you will have to use `nuget.exe` restore instead. Look my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53635910/213871) for that.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore it is possible:

> MSBuild: use the msbuild /t:restore command, which restores packages packages listed in the project file (PackageReference only). Available only in NuGet 4.x+ and MSBuild 15.1+, which are included with Visual Studio 2017. `nuget restore` and `dotnet restore` both use this command for applicable projects.