# Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget-package, dotnet-restore

I have a web app in dot net along with other projects. when i open the .sln file and publish the web project, it does. But, when I try to publish the web proj using command line and .csproj, it gives an error. "Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore."

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, first I was using dotnet pusblish. the issue was resolved using msbuild

Comment: how was it resolved using msbuild?  I just upgraded nuget, and followed this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrate-to-automatic-package-restore-visual-studio  and now my msbuild is failing - says nothing to restore!

Comment: @DanielWilliams did you resolve this?

Comment: @SulemanMehmood can you please post the solution?

Comment: @Nishant Please use msbuild to build the web projects using command line. it will fix the issue

Comment: If you use msbuild.exe -t:restore, you need to change to pakage reference in order for that to work (and not say "nothing to restore"). In Visual Studio, go to Tools->Options->NuGet package manager -> General. Change package management to PackageReference and then remove all your Nuget dependencies and re-add them. This will modify your .proj files and then -t:restore will work.

Comment: @kernelony or you can use the `-p:RestorePackagesConfig=true` switch as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209365/682203)

Comment: @Nishant Can you please post the solution for this, thank you

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem in a batch file I use to build a UWP component for release. The build command is

```
%MSBUILD% CartoType\src\main\single_library\uwp\CartoType\CartoType.sln -p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
```

where %MSBUILD% is the full path to msbuild. I first added an **msbuild** command with the `-t:restore` option and got the message reported by the original poster ('Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore').

The solution was to add this command *before* the command given above:

```
%MSBUILD% CartoType\src\main\single_library\uwp\CartoType\CartoType.sln -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true -t:restore
```

Comment: thank you, this worked for me. `msbuild .\mysln.sln /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"`

Answer (score 2):

I got this after converting my `csproj` to `vs2019` format and running `dotnet test`. The solution was to ensure i had the right test adapter and framework. My `csproj` files had both the old `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` reference and the new `MSTest.TestAdapter` + `MSTest.TestFramework` +  `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`.
I kept the new ones and my tests were run.