# Nuget dependencies loading except for ConfigCat in GitHub Actions

Tags: msbuild, github-actions, nuget-package-restore, configcat

For some reason GitHub Actions is not pulling in one Nuget package [ConfigCat.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConfigCat.Client) but works fine for the remaining 20 packages.  This is one solution with many projects.  It works fine in VS Build as well as local msbuild command.  I have another simple solution in GitHub Actions that works fine as well.  I'm using a win-2019 server runner with .NET SDK 5.0.  I get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ConfigCat.Client, Version=6.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d28b16a067d7bbe2, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I'm running this (restore & build):

```
msbuild $env:Solution_Path /t:Restore /p:Configuration=$env:Configuration /p:RuntimeIdentifier=$env:RuntimeIdentifier
msbuild $env:Solution_Path /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration=Release /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideloadOnly /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile=$certificatePath /p:PackageCertificatePassword=${{ secrets.Pfx_Key }}
```

Errors from log file (could it be related to processorArchitecture=MSIL?)

```
2022-08-28T03:05:23.6891561Z   Primary reference "ConfigCat.Client, Version=6.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d28b16a067d7bbe2, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
2022-08-28T03:05:23.6894672Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ConfigCat.Client, Version=6.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d28b16a067d7bbe2, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\DataProduction\DataProduction\BigLebowski\Services\FeatureFlagService\FeatureFlagService.csproj]
2022-08-28T03:05:23.6896617Z           For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
2022-08-28T03:05:23.6897448Z           Considered "D:\a\DataProduction\DataProduction\BigLebowski\packages\ConfigCat.Client.6.5.1\lib\net45\ConfigCat.Client.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

I've also tried changing the Platform to x64 with the same results.
Any insight or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems the restore couldn't download the NuGet package. Are there any errors in your log related to restore? What other dependencies do you have in your project? I'm one of the ConfigCat developers, so I'd recommend to contact us via our [support](https://configcat.com/support/) to get help faster resolving this issue.

Comment: I updated the description with the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Péter Csajtai for solving the problem.  The project was using packages.config and not restoring the nuget package as a result.  Adding the parameter /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true to the restore resolved the issue.  See also this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956184/msbuild-and-package-restore-with-packages-config)